# The Value HexBytes(*hex string*) is 97 bytes but should be 32 when using Contract.transact()

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

I have made a simple smart contract which is below

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract ECDS {

Computer[] public computer;

event gotComputers(string _msg);
event addedComputer(string _msg, uint _cores, uint _cache, uint _coresVM, bool _mining);

struct Computer {
    uint cores;
    uint cache;
    uint coresVM;
    bool mining;
}

function addComputer(uint _cores, uint _cache, uint _coresVM, bool _mining) returns (bool success){
    Computer memory newComputer;
    
    newComputer.cores = _cores;
    newComputer.cache = _cache;
    newComputer.coresVM = _coresVM;
    newComputer.mining = _mining;
    
    computer.push(newComputer);
    addedComputer("A computer was added", _cores, _cache, _coresVM, _mining);
    return true;   
}

function getComputer() constant returns (uint[],uint[],uint[],bool[]){
    uint length = computer.length;
    
    uint[] memory coresList = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory cacheList = new uint[](length);
    uint[] memory coresVMList = new uint[](length);
    bool[] memory miningList = new bool[](length);
    
    for(uint i = 0; i < length; i++){
        Computer memory currentComputer;
        currentComputer = computer[i];
        
        coresList[i] = currentComputer.cores;
        cacheList[i] = currentComputer.cache;
        coresVMList[i] = currentComputer.coresVM;
        miningList[i] = currentComputer.mining;
    }
    
    gotComputers("Got the list of computers");
    return (coresList, cacheList, coresVMList, miningList);
}

function availableFreeCores() constant returns (uint[]){
    uint length = computer.length;
    
    uint[] memory freeCoresList = new uint[](length);
    for(uint i = 0; i < length; i++){
        Computer memory currentComputer;
        currentComputer = computer[i];
        
        uint freeCores = currentComputer.cores - (currentComputer.cache / 2);
        
        freeCoresList[i] = freeCores;
    }
    return freeCoresList;
}
}
```

Then I am using call().getComputer() successfully in a python program, but I get an error when using transact().addComputer(cores, cache, coresVM, True). Python shown below.

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider, IPCProvider
import json

contractAdress = '0x2343A6d7c85Ab43f94E50C128A7d3109A3647a1D'
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('52.169.42.101:30303'))
with open('factory.json', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)
web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())

fContract = web3.eth.contract(contractAdress, abi=abi)
cores = 12
cache = 15
coresVM = 0
mining = True
fContract.transact().addComputer(cores, cache, coresVM, True)
print('Computers',fContract.call().getComputer())
```

If I comment out the transact().addComputer it runs successfully and returns the correct values. But with it included in the program the full error that I get is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ECDS.py", line 15, in <module>
fContract.transact().addComputer(cores, cache, coresVM, True)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/contract.py", line 821, in transact_with_contract_function
txn_hash = contract.web3.eth.sendTransaction(transact_transaction)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/eth.py", line 211, in sendTransaction
get_buffered_gas_estimate(self.web3, transaction),
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/utils/transactions.py", line 160, in get_buffered_gas_estimate
gas_limit = get_block_gas_limit(web3)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/utils/transactions.py", line 151, in get_block_gas_limit
block = web3.eth.getBlock(block_identifier)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/eth.py", line 127, in getBlock
[block_identifier, full_transactions],
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/manager.py", line 74, in request_blocking
response = self._make_request(method, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/manager.py", line 57, in _make_request
return request_func(method, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/middleware/attrdict.py", line 20, in middleware
response = make_request(method, params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/middleware/formatting.py", line 32, in middleware
formatter(response['result']),
 File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__ (cytoolz/functoolz.c:3996)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/utils/formatters.py", line 62, in apply_formatter_if
return formatter(value)
 File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__ (cytoolz/functoolz.c:3996)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ethereum_utils-0.5.1-py3.5.egg/eth_utils/functional.py", line 33, in inner
return callback(fn(*args, **kwargs))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/utils/formatters.py", line 72, in apply_formatters_to_dict
yield key, formatters[key](item)
 File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 232, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__ (cytoolz/functoolz.c:3996)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/web3-3.16.1-py3.5.egg/web3/middleware/pythonic.py", line 111, in to_hexbytes
result, len(result), num_bytes
ValueError: The value HexBytes('0xd783010703846765746887676f312e392e31856c696e7578000000000000000019905343b07339c85f1797c521d65dc9238743fdc52261c5ee4a4bd39004426e4b06c492df58bfbb037151d294187535732d23b5c768a83f452ceda2d5b6128400') is 97 bytes, but should be 32
```

I tried decoding the Hex to ASCII and I got that it is related to the geth go client, but I have not found any way to fix the error.

Comment: Which network are you on, mainnet? You installed web3.py from source; which commit are you on? (it's in alpha state) Can you print the result of `web3.manager.request_blocking('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', False])`?

Comment: I am on the rinkeby network. I am on the latest commit from Oct 30th. I made a small python program just to try the .request_blocking and got `'Request for id:eth_getBlockByNumber not found'`

Comment: I deployed the contract using the Ethereum Wallet on Ubuntu and with that it installed geth. I am thinking about doing a clean Virtual Machine and trying building everything from scratch again instead of using the Ethereum Wallet to see if that can fix the problem

Comment: `'Request for id:eth_getBlockByNumber not found'` is a very strange error, maybe from connecting to a broken client. I notice that you're creating `web3` twice above. Are you maybe connecting to a different client than you intend to? `IPCProvider` with no arguments tries to connect to the go-ethereum (geth) client -- although some alternate clients create an IPC connection file where geth normally puts it in order to be compatible. Any luck with a fresh reinstall?

Comment: Fresh reinstall seems to have done it. I did a fresh VM with ropsten network not rinkeby and it is working fine. Still have the other VM and have played with it a couple of times but still haven't gotten anything to work. Leaning towards it was an install but of some sort but who knows.

Comment: FWIW, I think that the node was not functioning correctly. Somewhere that web3 was expecting a hash result, it was instead receiving: `b'\xd7\x83\x01\x07\x03\x84geth\x87go1.9.1\x85linux\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x90SC\xb0s9\xc8_\x17\x97\xc5!\xd6]\xc9#\x87C\xfd\xc5"a\xc5\xeeJK\xd3\x90\x04BnK\x06\xc4\x92\xdfX\xbf\xbb\x03qQ\xd2\x94\x18u5s-#\xb5\xc7h\xa8?E,\xed\xa2\xd5\xb6\x12\x84\x00'`

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an error in node installation or start up in which something isn't running correctly. I ended up doing a fresh reinstall of all the related components and now it seems to be working!